# Android Studio Gradle does not download maven depedencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am quite new to Android development and trying to write some test code. I have downloaded Android Studio 1.3 version and created testapp. I am trying to add com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0 depedency but somehow it's not getting downloaded.

Here is Project level build.gradle file.

```
   buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}
```

Here is Module level build.gradle file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

After reading other posts on similar topics I also confirmed that Gradle > Global Gradle settings > Offline work is not checked. Still somehow facebook depedency is not getting downloaded.
Any suggestions what could be the issue? Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` you have to add

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
```

It this way gradle knows where are the dependencies to download.
It is somenthing different from the repositories inside the `buildscript` block.

Otherwise you can add in the *top-level* `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In this case, the repository block is valid for all modules in the project.

Comment: and possibly `repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for quick reply. @Gabriele adding repository in allprojects tag resolved the issue.  allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter() 
    }
}                                                                                                                 I had fb depedency in module gradle file and gradle uses "allprojects" configurations are used for building the modules.

Comment: @SampadaPatil Yes. You can add the repository block in the single module or in the top-level file. In this case this block is valid for all modules in the project. I've just updated the answer. Mark as resolved if it solves your issue. It can be useful for other users.

Comment: @Gabriele Yes, I marked it as resolved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the error AndroidStudio is showing? (check on the Gradle Console, on the Run section and Android Monitor section)

One possible option that comes to my mind is that you don't have the lastest Android Support repository / Google repository installed: Check for updates on your Android SDK Manager.

Comment: The facebook dependency isn't in SDK Manager. Also it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry about using 'an answer' but i don't have reputation to make comments.
About facebook dependency i know about that. But facebook has it's own dependencies that I'm almost sure include some android/google ones. That's why it could fail without the repositories updated